# Cross-browser positioning of divs

Tags: css, hover, position

I'm trying to make an animated menu using `:hover` using two `div`s with the same content but when I have more than one button and I hover on it, the second div shows up 1 or 2 pixels lower in Chrome but not in Firefox. I made an example with two menus, one with two buttons (`BUTTON1`,`BUTTON2`) and one with only one button (`BUTTON3`): http://jsfiddle.net/Revolt/VHuyw/

Comment: The buttons and hover states look the using Opera…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top` to your `.button` class: http://jsfiddle.net/VHuyw/2/